# php exec: bad php backslash escaping or what?

Tags: php, escaping, exec

I have this command:

```
exec(sprintf('%s %s dump_data output', escapeshellarg($apps . 'pdftk' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'pdftk.exe'), escapeshellarg(self::winEscapeShellArgFix($file, array()))), $output);
```

the result of sprintf is this:

```
"\\127.0.0.1\binary\win32\pdftk\pdftk.exe" "//127.0.0.1/uploads\1-16knje01g1drjagii61j3515a94.pdf" dump_data output
```

running this command from exec will give no result, but if I run it from windows cmd it will work correctly. After I trying millions of commands I understand that the problem is that php is using as escape backslash the backslashes inside the sprintf output:

```
**\\**127......
```

Any one knows why this happens? I have all magic OFF.

**EDIT:**
if i will execute:

```
exec("\\127.0.0.1\binary\win32\pdftk\pdftk.exe //127.0.0.1/uploads\1-16knje01g1drjagii61j3515a94.pdf dump_data output",$outarr);
```

or

```
exec('\\127.0.0.1\binary\win32\pdftk\pdftk.exe //127.0.0.1/uploads\1-16knje01g1drjagii61j3515a94.pdf dump_data output',$outarr);
```

it will not work

**EDIT2:**
I debug and it is not an escaping problem the command actually is good, IT seems to be a exec problem, that is not returning the  output. it works in a iis web server but doesnt work in another iis webserver.

Comment: Please reword your diagnosis. I cannot quite understand "php is using as escape backslash the backslashes inside the sprintf output." Thanks!

Comment: "\\" is the appropriate beginning for a network share. Are you saying that you only want one "\"?

Comment: yes I want to point to a network share, but "\\" will not work: the results is \127.0.0.1 and I dont want that even I am using escapeshellchars

Answer (score 2):

albanx,  it's not `sprintf` doing it to you, its the `escapeshellarg` which is adding the backslashes.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: the problem is not adding, but it is removing them, escapeshellarg in practice should preserve them

Comment: I just noticed something I didn't see before, you have a "slash mismatch" in the argument.  You have opposing slashes here: "/uploads\".  I've never used pdftk, but I'm certain you can't have the slashes going both ways.I'm not certain what `winEscapeShellArgFix` fix, is, but I'd check there next.

Comment: it something strange with php, it seems that it takes the \\ as a escape of \, even it is inside a string

Comment: Ah, I see.  Have you tried 4 backlashes?  It would theoretically then see it at 2 real slashes and go through.

Comment: yes in this way I can resolve, but the problem is that this \\127.0.0.1\binary\win32\pdftk\pdftk.exe is inside a variable, in realty I have 'exec("$pdftkpath $pdffile dump_data output",$outarr);'